# Is it possible to stop the onslaught of iOS banner notifications coming in one-by-one after disabling Do Not Disturb?

Tags: ios, notifications

My question is mostly in the subject line, but I'll add more clarity.

Whenever my device is in Do Not Disturb mode, it supresses all notifications exactly like one would expect.  The issue is when I disable it in the morning either manually, or canceling my wake-up alarm, the notifications that use banners all come streaming in one after the other after the other after the other, etc.

It is beyond frustrating, especially when you're trying to do something like reading the subject of an email in the mail app.  A banner notification comes in and covers it. I swipe it away. Another banner immediately comes in, covering it right back up again! I swipe that one away... Another banner comes in!!

My choices are...

1. Turn Do Not Disturb back on (delaying the problem until later)
2. Dismissing all notifications from the Home Screen (so now I don't know what they were!)
3. Hurl the phone at the wall with sufficient velocity to stop said notifications permanently (always feels like the 'right option' at the time, but it usually subsides moments later.)

Simply put, there is *never* a case where to me it makes sense to stream them all in one-by-one at the top of the screen like that, *especially* if I have manually swiped them away.

In a perfect world, you'd get a single banner that said 'While you were away, you received xxx notifications' and tap it to go to the notification center, but I'd be happy with the ability to have it the way it is now so long as I'm given the option to say 'Stop notification banners for already-delivered notifications.'

Point being even if I did want to read them all right then, that is the most inefficient way to do so!

So... does anyone know how to say 'Hey... stop showing the @#$% banners one by one!  It is beyond intrusive and incredibly frustrating.

Comment: I don’t get this at all. Are the notifications from a specific application? I wonder if it queued local notifications as I use DND extensively for days in some cases - more than half the day on multiple devices and can’t trigger a deluge of notifications despite trying and using this feature quite a lot.  Maybe I’ve suppressed banners on the offending apps already - I’m quick to ban an app - notification banners are rare for me in general.

Comment: I've also *never* experienced this

Comment: Just updated the question to indicate this is only for transient-banner-based notifications.  All other types of notifications don't apply.  In my case, I have banners turned on for almost all of them.

Comment: Do you have them going to Notification Center? They should appear in notification center regardless of DND and they don't appear again. Perhaps that's what's happening here - if so, don't disable them going to notification center

Answer (score 1):

Allow those notifications to go to the Notification Center as well. If they go to the Notification Center, they will not be queued for banners while DND is on (or while the screen is off).

(From @Ezekiel's comment above)